# Arduino rgb loop

Tags: arduino

So I have an rgb led and I can change the color with:

```
    setColor(r, g, b);
```

I want a loop to loop through all the possible combinations how can I do this?

Comment: Other than with for loops?

Comment: many ways to do this, for example [here](https://gist.github.com/jamesotron/766994). Clearly this questions shows little to no research effort.

Comment: This is a pure Arduino software question, and so IMHO should be migrated to the Arduino stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with nested for loops:

```
int R;
int G;
int B;

void loop()
{
 for (R = 0 ; R < 256 ; R++)
{
   for (G = 0 ; G < 256 ; G++)
   {
      for (B = 0 ; B < 256 ; B++)
      {
        setColor(R,G,B);
      }
   }
};
}
```

It would be really nice if you put some more effort into your work...
Hope it helps. 
Best of Luck!!

Comment: The question shows no research effort (see [help]), and so it *might* have helped the OP a bit more if you'd given some advice and direction rather than the entire answer (though your C, with its incorrect `};` suggests that you are learning it, and not yet expert). The old saying is [give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). Giving an answer robs the OP of the opportunity to learn!

Comment: @gbulmer maybe i was caught up for finding something I finally know the answer to - yes im still learning :) . And i cant agree more on what you said , perhaps next time i'll try to teach rather than provide plain answers! Thx :)